# "skipping: no hosts matched" issue with Vagrant and Ansible

Tags: debian, vagrant, virtualbox, ansible

I have installed Vagrant, VirtualBox and Ansible and trying to run provision over one host but it always returns "skipping: no hosts matched"

The head of my playbook file looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  user: vagrant
  sudo: yes
```

and my `/etc/ansible/hosts` file looks like this:

```
[webservers]
webserver1
```

I tried putting the IP address there but had the same result. I have added my ssh key to the server and added webserver1 host to both `.ssh/config` and `/etc/hosts`.

I can `ssh vagrant@webserver1` fine without being prompted for a password, thanks to using the ssh key.

What am I missing here?

- Host: Debian 7.2
- Client machine: Debian 7
- Virtualbox: 4.1.18
- Vangrantup: 1.4.1
- Ansible: 1.5

Answer (score 30):

It could help to post your Vagrantfile and your ansible inventory file.

- Are you using the default ansible provider of vagrant?

  did you specify the `inventory_path`?

```
 config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
   ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
   ansible.inventory_path = "provisioning/ansible_hosts"
 end
```

- Are you launching it the through the a vagrant ssh with `--connection=local` try a /etc/ansible/hosts

```
[webserver1]
127.0.0.1              ansible_connection=local
```

- Are you using the ansibleLocal provider / vagrant plugin?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I wasn't aware that you could specify your own hosts file. I thought it would only checkout /etc/ansible/hosts.

Thank you.

Comment: *Off topic*   @Dubby You should consider this answer as the best one and give credit to mestachs

Comment: If you still get errors (e.g. `ERROR! Specified --limit does not match any hosts`), you might also need to add `ansible.limit = "<group/machine name>"` to the settings.

Comment: Just a note to this answer, besides that this is The Correct Answer for ansible managed inventory.
Vagrant gets in the way, and adds an implicit ansible.limit = webserver1 if the machine is named like it. If your role acts on multiple targets, imagine some trigger on other machine. This won't work unless explicitly setting ansible.limit = all, and then let ansible do its own limitation by the defined hosts.. Vagrant tries to do too many things and abstractions, yet this is one of the things it shouldnt do.

Answer (score 27):

Make sure you're running ansible-playbook command instead of pure ansible command.

Answer (score 21):

I think you can also do this without a hosts file, by assigning the Ansible groups in your Vagrant file.

If you don't have multiple machines in your Vagrant file your box will probably be called "default" and you will be able to add multiple Ansible groups with the following code.

***Code:***

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.groups = {
        "webservers" => ["default"],
        "dev_enviroment" => ["default"]
    }

    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
end
```

Comment: This is perfect, it lets me use Vagrant's auto generated host file.

Comment: Does anyone know where ansible.groups is documented?  I can't find it in the Vagrant documentation on Ansibile provisioning.

Comment: Hi @Robert its on this page if you search for "groups" https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html

Comment: The `"default"` entry did it, thanks! Using it specifically for vagrant btw, have a separate inventory/hosts file when provisioning production servers.

Answer (score 9):

Changing hosts to "all" worked for me.

```
---
- hosts: all
  user: vagrant
  sudo: yes
```

Comment: Note that the playbook will target every host listed in your  Ansible inventory if you run it with `ansible-playbook`

Comment: This should be avoided, and doesn't solve the hosts skipping. It only hides it. If your inventory has more than one machine and you wish to provision each with different roles, this sets the same roles on each machine.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that the syntax on the head of your playbook file is incorrect, (it has extra dashes where it shouldn't). It should look like this instead:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  user: vagrant
  sudo: yes
```

Comment: Sorry, I do have it that way but entered it into the post incorrectly. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the vagrant documentation (http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html), when you use Ansible to provision, vagrant will automatically create an host file named `vagrant_ansible_inventory_default` which will use vagrant `vm.config` information (like your VM IP, remote ssh port).

So just add your playbook path using the `ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"`

Comment: I didn't find this to be the case.  When I ran "vagrant provision" without a hosts declaration in my provision.yml file, I got the error "hosts declaration is required".

Answer (score 2):

I tried pointing the groups to  default vagrant box and it worked. Refer 
https://gagor.pl/2015/12/ansible-on-vagrant-skipping-no-hosts-matched/

```
ansible.groups = {
  'webservers' => ['default']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your playbook in verbose mode by adding -vvvv in the end. Ansible uses host file from /etc/ansible/hosts
add the below

You can check what inventory file is being used by your ansible by below

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0.2
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Then check your host file if it contains the exact group for host

```
 vim /etc/ansible/hosts
 [webserver1]
 IP of machine
```

check by running the below command

```
ansible -m ping 10.0.3.145 (IP Of machine)
10.0.3.145 | SUCCESS => {
"changed": false, 
"ping": "pong"
```

}

This should fix the issue.

Answer (score -5):

make sure you use this command "ansible-playbook -i yourhosts your.yml"